# set asp.net impersonation in thread state

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, threadpool

I have an asp.net application that is running in impersonation state in IIS7, this application is starting a new thread and according to MSDN:

"When impersonation is required on the new thread, your application **should save** the security token (WindowsIdentity.Token Property) from the original thread as part of the state for the completion thread."

but i am not sure how to this

could anyone help?

thanks

Doron

Edit: I found the answer in the following great post: http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=650&pId=2

Comment: This is an internal site I am working on and the action started from the page is in another thread because its a long action so to avoid from keeping the user waiting